# Name errors using Monitor and Tally in SimPy

Tags: python, pip, simpy

Hello I am trying to simulate a discrete event using SimPy in python, but both Monitor and Tally classes of SimPy return a name error. According to the [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/simpyclassic/downloads/pdf/stable/) (page 54) after importing SimPy I should be able to define a new monitor with `m = Monitor(name="name)`.

When I do this it returns `NameError: name Monitor' is not defined`. I have also tried it as `m=simpy.Monitor` in which case I receive an attribute error.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older (2.x) version of simpy did have Monitor and Tally available.  That went away with (I think) version 3.  See here for information on the most current release: https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/monitoring.html

Basically, for things you have control/access (such as processes you create), just keep a record of the times/events/counters you need (e.g., to how many minutes was spent being repaired, have the repair process keep track of start time, then calculate timeInRepair = stopTime-startTime).  For other items of interest, such as resources, you don't have direct access to record what happens when states change.  The documentation shows an example of how to use a wrapper to modify the pre and post methods for the resource.